# Redirecting index.php to domain root only without any GET variables

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

On my site [www.apptic.me](http://www.apptic.me) I used to have a redirect rule to always redirect index.php to the domain root.

I realized that this made the mobile layouts at the bottom [here](http://www.apptic.me/index.php?desk=0) and [here](http://www.apptic.me/index.php?desk=1) lose the "index.php" portion of the URL and PHP was no longer able to read the GET variables.

So I deleted the redirect. But now when users navigate to plain old [www.apptic.me/index.php](http://www.apptic.me/index.php) the "index.php" stays. I want to redirect index.php to the root if there are no GET variables.

Is this possible and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: What's your index file? Correct me if I'm wrong. You have an HTML file that you want to load in case no $_GET parameters are present and load index.php if $_GET isn't empty?

Comment: Have you check the .htaccess file in http://html5boilerplate.com/?

Comment: No, the $_GET parameters just result in a different CSS file being loaded and a couple of different tags. Same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: What does this do specifically?

Comment: This will externally redirect every `http://domain.com/dir/index.php` to `http://domain.com/dir`

Answer (score 0):

PHP can still read the $_GET variables even with redirection so there is no longer any problem with redirection.